# The MOSI pin of SPI1 on STM32L073 is not giving output without pull-up resistor

Tags: stm32, spi, pullup

I am working on SPI communication with STM32L073.

I download the example program of ST to MCU but SPI1 did not work. So I looked at the SCK pin of MCU with oscilloscope and it works fine. But when I look at the MOSI pin, I did not see anything. After that I pulled-up the MOSI pin with 10k resistor and I saw that it worked but not high enough which is not 3V3.

So what should I do to get enough output value from MOSI pin?

**Pinout:**
SP1,
MOSI: GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_12.
MISO: GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_11.
SCK:  GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5.
NSS:  GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4.

Thanks...

**Edit1:** I tested SPI with Nucleo-073rz. SPI worked just fine. But when I test it with my pcb, MOSI pin doesn't give output at all but SCK, NSS are fine.

**Edit2:** We replaced chip to stm32L152, it works!!! But I need to use STM32L073.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Could you please show the schematic and perhaps also add a scope picture of MOSI using this 10k resistor?

Comment: Try a 1k resistor.

Comment: I tried 1.3k resistor but this time output level stays high all time.

Comment: With 10k pull up, the voltage level of MOSI is less than half of voltage level of SCK. I am at home so I cannot add the scope picture:D

Comment: Do you have the GPIO pins configured as weak pull-up and pull-down?

Answer (score 2):

We found the problem which is we did not connect VDD_USB to VDD. Because PA11 and PA12 pins can be used as I/O only if VDD_USB pin is supplied between VDD_min and VDD_max.

Comment: seriously? good to know. I better fix this on the schematic I have right now. Where is this mentioned in the manual?

Comment: It is mentioned in the datasheet of STM32L073.

Comment: Man. Buried as a footnote in the Electrical Characteristics section of the datasheet, not the reference manual.